# NodeJs HTTP Request Not working with proxy (407)

Tags: node.js, http, request, http-status-code-407

I've been using the NPM Request package for years now and despite the fact that it's deprecated, it has always worked perfectly for my needs and I haven't ever had any issues up until today...

I am trying to do a regular GET request with a user:pass authenticated proxy and some additional headers - the same thing I've done a thousand times in the past, however this time the url is **HTTP** instead of HTTPS.

For whatever reason because the link is HTTP it is messing with my proxy authentication and for whatever reason is returning a response code of **407** and the response body shows an error stating **Cache Access Denied (ERR_CACHE_ACCESS_DENIED)**. This is where I'm confused as to what to do because I know for a fact that there shouldn't be anything wrong with my proxy authentication since its the same thing I've done for years and years.

**Request Code:**

```
const request = require('request').defaults({
    timeout: 30000,
    gzip: true,
    forever: true
});

cookieJar = request.jar();
proxyUrl = "http://proxyUsername:proxyPassword@proxyDomain:proxyPort";

request({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://mylink.com",
    proxy: proxyUrl,
    jar: cookieJar,
    headers: {
      "Proxy-Authorization": new Buffer('proxyUsername:proxyPassword').toString('base64'),
      "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
      "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36",
    },
    followAllRedirects: true
}, (err, resp, body) => {

    if (err || resp.statusCode != 200) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(resp.statusCode);
            console.log(resp.body);

        }
        return;
    }

    console.log(resp.body);
});
```

**Snippet of Response Body (Status Code 407):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta type="copyright" content="Copyright (C) 1996-2019 The Squid Software Foundation and contributors">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>ERROR: Cache Access Denied</title>
<style type="text/css"><!-- 

body
:lang(fa) { direction: rtl; font-size: 100%; font-family: Tahoma, Roya, sans-serif; float: right; }
:lang(he) { direction: rtl; }
 --></style>
</head><body id=ERR_CACHE_ACCESS_DENIED>
<div id="titles">
<h1>ERROR</h1>
<h2>Cache Access Denied.</h2>
</div>
<hr>
...
<p>Sorry, you are not currently allowed to request http://mylink.com from this cache until you have authenticated yourself.</p>
...
```

**Other things to note:**

- I have also connected to the exact same proxy on my browser and gone to the same site and it works perfectly so it's not an issue with the proxy itself.
- If I remove the proxy from the request it works perfectly, so maybe I have configured the request wrong for HTTP is all I can think of

Now as I said this exact code works flawlessly with any HTTPS link so that's where I'm stumped. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the Proxy-Authorization header to **Proxy-Authenticate** and that seemed to work perfectly. I have no clue why it requires that for HTTP but there you go, not much documentation on the matter...